# Combining two too large plots

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting a result of a `bic.mlogit` function. Since I have 13 IVs, the plot is too large to fit at once to the plot environment in R Studio and it prompts me to

> Hit Return to see next plot:

The thing is I would like to export both plots to a one .png file because they're basically one plot, but too large for R Studio console to show at once (please see below).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

### First part of the plot

[image]

### Second part of the same plot

[image]

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the plot function in `png` or `pdf` and `dev.close` and the looking at the resulting file? This is the standard method in R (sans interactive work with Rstudio).

Comment: Please provide code you've tried, otherwise it'll be suggestions on plots that might have no relevance to you. (You might be able to base it on `mtcars` or `iris` to keep the data simple.)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but it sounds like you need to set `par(mfrow = ...)` or `par(mfcol = ...)` to dimensions big enough to fit 14 plots.

Answer (score 0):

Have not found an R solution, but I have found a rather unelegant one - well just combine the two resulting *.png files into one with a help of some online tool and that's it :]